# ld returned 1 exit status error with passing parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This compiles perfectly fine.

```
const int NUM_PLAYERS = 10;

struct wrType
{
string name[NUM_PLAYERS];
string team[NUM_PLAYERS];
int catches[NUM_PLAYERS];
int yards[NUM_PLAYERS];
int td[NUM_PLAYERS];
double ypc[NUM_PLAYERS];
};

void populateList(wrType[], ifstream&);

int main(int args, char* argv[])
{
wrType *wide;
char select;
ifstream in;
in.open(argv[1]);

/*populateList(wrType wide, ifstream in); code causing error*/

}

void populateList(wrType wide, ifstream in)
{   
};
```

As soon as I uncomment the following code

> 'populateList(wide, in);'

I get the following error

> 'ld returned 1 exit status error'

After compiling.
I have looked at many forums and have not been able to solve the problem. We recently got into structs and classes and I am not sure if I am misunderstanding a concept or how to get this to work.

The code is supposed pass a file through the command line and then later on be able to access it and sort with bubble sort by different stats of football players which is 10 players. I don't want my hand held which is why I left the rest out for me to struggle with later. The code works without the function and within main but as soon as I try and call the function with the code I have, it gives me an error as stated.

Also when I try to pass them as pointers the it gives me a can't convert myType* to myType

Update with the full error:

> 'In function `main':
>   (.text+0xad): undefined reference to`populateList(wrType*, std::basic_ifstream >&)'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status'

Edit 2:
The code with

> 'populateList(wrType wide, ifstream in);'

returns the following error:

In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:

> 34:22: error: expected primary-expression before ‘wide’
>   populateList(wrType wide, ifstream in);
>                         ^
>   34:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘in’ populateList(wrType wide, ifstream in);

Comment: 1. Is this the only error message you are getting? 2. What is the uncommented code supposed to do? 3. Are you sure you are using Visual C++?

Comment: Is the commented out code trying to call your populateList function?  You want `populateList(wide, in);` if that's the case.  Your function says what types it expects, when you call it, you pass instances of those types.  (And they don't have to be called `wide` and `in`, by the way.  It's fine that they are, though.)

Comment: your declaration and definition differ - you have to fix it. Linker will not find the function, it will think it is different overload. When calling function - you do not pass types only variables: `populateList(wide, in);`

Comment: I am using gedit on ubuntu and g++ to compile. Yeah the commented out code is what I am trying to use and what is giving me the error.

Comment: Removed unrelated "visual c++" tag. What version of g++ are you using? This should give a compilation error, not a linker error. [demo](https://ideone.com/hocNge)

Comment: gcc version 5.4.0

Comment: "'ld returned 1 exit status error'" is never the only error message, and this error message cannot be a result of compiling the cone you have posted.

Comment: I have updated it with the correct information now.

Comment: I very much doubt `void populateList(wide, in) {...}` "compiles perfectly fine".

Comment: Please learn to indent code so the structure can be seen. Most programming editors will do it automatically for you.

Comment: I am sorry. I copied it over from my virtualbox to my windows page. Also first time using stackoverflow. I will make to comment my lines and have it indented. Became an after thought while I was scrambling to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in this code.

1. ```
   struct wrType
   {
   string name[NUM_PLAYERS];
   ...
   };
   ```

   You need an array of records, not a record of parallel arrays. Remove all the `[...]` in the above `struct`.
2. ```
   wrType *wide;
   ```

   You want an array of these structures, not a pointer.

   ```
   wrType wide[NUM_PLAYERS];
   ```
3. ```
   populateList(wrType wide, ifstream in);
   ```

   This is not a correct function call syntax.
4. ```
   void populateList(wrType wide, ifstream in)
   ```

   This doesn't match an earlier declaration

   ```
   void populateList(wrType[], ifstream&);
   ```

You need to build your entire program around this declaration. First, bring your `populateList` definition into accord with that line

```
void populateList(wrType[] wide, ifstream& in)
{
}
```

then fill in the body. Note that lines like

```
in >> wide.name[x];
```

are no longer correct, you need to change them.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the issue. I just need to keep on practicing and keep on reading.  I originally had it as wrType wide[NUM_PLAYERS]; but never changed the function declaration to (wrType[] wide, ifstream& in). For some reason I thought having it typed 'wrType[]' was wrong. I am not sure where I got that concept from. And for a second I thought I was getting a grip of all c++. Rookie mistake on my part.